# Can I read the chrome://sync page from an extension?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want to access the `chrome://sync` page to get the synchronisation status of the browser. Is there a way I can do it and how?

Answer (score 0):

There is no public extension API for accessing the `chrome://sync` data, and you can not inject JavaScript code into `chrome://` URLs.

Comment: No workaround (and any you found would be considered a fairly interesting security bug. :) ). What's the use case you're interested in implementing? Please do feel free to file a request at http://new.crbug.com/: If it's something we can support, I'd be happy to throw it into the proper queue.

Comment: Since there's no Sync Now Button, and it's needed to change bookmarks to trigger synchronization. I developed an extension yo do that.

The Extension creates a bookmark, and then deletes it. This way Sync is triggered, and no change to bookmarks are made. 

I tried to get the chrome://sync page to get the status of the sync so when it's ready again i show the ready status in badge.

Thanks for the help